# symfony2: including inline javascript

Tags: symfony

I've added some javascript code below to show some photos using a slide show jquery plugin.

```
//parent template
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/canalonesfrontend/js/slides.min.jquery.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}

//child template
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    $(function(){
        $("#slides").slides();
    });
{% endblock %}
```

The problem: the code is shown in the web page directly:

```
Some content
$(function(){ $("#slides").slides(); });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to wrap with `<script></script>` tag around your code

```
//child template
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#slides").slides();
    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

I hope you understood the problem!